# eks assume role is not permitted on user

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to run an automated build on my aws codebuild project.  I have the following statement in my buildpsec.yaml file

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --name ticket-api --region us-west-1 --role-arn arn:aws:iam::12345:role/service-role/CodeBuild-API-Build-service-role`

I get the following error

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::12345:assumed-role/CodeBuild-API-Build-service-role/AWSCodeBuild-99c25416-7046-416e-b5d9-4bff1f4992f3 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::12345:role/service-role/CodeBuild-API-Build-service-role
```

I'm not sure whats the role `arn:aws:sts::12345:assumed-role/CodeBuild-API-Build-service-role/AWSCodeBuild-99c25416-7046-416e-b5d9-4bff1f4992f3` especially the part `AWSCodeBuild-99c25416-7046-416e-b5d9-4bff1f4992f3`.  Is it something unique to the current user ?

Also I think the current user is already assigned to the role based on what its trying to assign.

If I run the same command without role `aws eks update-kubeconfig --name ticket-api --region us-west-1` then it works but when I try `kubectl version` after that I get the following error

```
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```